# Can't submit changes to database or page controls

Tags: asp.net, linq

I've got a pretty simple page, consisting of two DropDownLists populated from the database, and a button. The purpose of the page is pretty simply to allow users to delete an entry from the database. When the button is clicked then a simple LINQ query is executed to delete the intended target, and remove the entry from the dropdownlists, but it doesn't work unless the response is redirected within that function, even if `SubmitChanges()` was called. Why would this happen?

Edit: Code

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = Database.DB.Data.GetTable<Database.tbl_module_>().Where(module => module.deptCode == ((User)Session["user"]).deptCode);
    foreach (var row in result)
    {
        this.listModuleCode.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(row.code));
        this.listModuleTitle.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(row.title));
    }
}
protected void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var DB = Database.DB.Data;
    var table = DB.GetTable<Database.tbl_module_>();
    var result = table.Where(module => module.deptCode == ((User)Session["user"]).deptCode && module.code == listModuleCode.SelectedItem.Text);
    listModuleCode.Items.Remove(listModuleCode.SelectedItem);
    listModuleTitle.Items.Remove(listModuleTitle.SelectedItem);
    table.DeleteAllOnSubmit(result);
    DB.SubmitChanges();
    Response.Redirect("deletemodule.aspx"); // redirect to this page
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We need to see your code to help more probably.  However:

You need to make sure it knows to delete on submit:

```
var q = db.Customers.Where(c => c.CustomerID == 2).Single();
db.Customers.DeleteOnSubmit(q);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Don't forget you can pass straight SQL to the object:

```
db.ExecuteCommand("DELETE FROM Customers WHERE ID = 2");
```

Which you might think is easier.

Comment: Thanks, but I did use DeleteOnSubmit and I did also call SubmitChanges.